# How to sum object column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sum

I need to make sum of column.


I think problem is in class, in action where I take performance_reports.


 I have associsations, so I get all reports related to user by next code:

```
    @performance_reports = Array.new
     current_user.websites.each do |website|
      reports = website.performance_reports
        reports.each do |report|
        @performance_reports.push(report)
      end
    end
```

In my view I'm printig each report and in the bottom I want to print summary of column.

Here is view:

```
   <% @performance_reports.each do |performance_report| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= performance_report.impressions %></td>
        <td><%= performance_report.clicks %></td>
        <td><%= performance_report.conversions %></td>
      </tr>
     <% end %>
     <tr>
      <td><%=  @performance_reports.count(:clicks)%></td>
      <td><%=  @performance_reports.count(:conversions)%></td>
     </tr>
```

All - clicls, conversions - are integer type.
This code is printing, that summary is 0.

**I have two questions: how to sum integers and how to sum not integer columns, which are not saving to database?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the method sum for this

```
@performance_reports.sum(:clicks)
```

it will also sum not integer also as it will return non integer type, to convert it in integer call like this

```
@performance_reports.sum(:clicks).to_i
```

Comment: not working - `undefined method `+ for #<PerformanceReport:`. It is working for Class.

Comment: It is working if I do it for `@performance_reports = @website.performance_reports`. I think error is caused by class of reports from THAT action - look at my code in question.

Comment: do it like this `PerformanceReport.sum(:clicks, :conditions => [id IN @performance_reports.map(&:_id)])` check the conditions part correct it accordingly I am not aware of correct syntax of `IN`

Comment: Thanks, but give me error.`C:/3108/0309/app/views/performance_reports/index.html.erb:55: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...(:clicks, :conditions => [id IN @performance_reports.map(&:_...`

Comment: correct answer is  `PerformanceReport.sum(:clicks, :conditions => ["id in (?)", @performance_reports.collect(&:id)]` I was not aware of correct `in` clause thats what I mentioned. Try this one I think it should work.

Comment: abhas , thanks ! it is correct. I have columns, which are not saving to database and evaluating in view. Maybe, I should move evaluating to controller ? I should make sum of this columns, can you suggest how to do it ?

Comment: for the values which are not saving to database, do the sum with the help of javascript...whenever a value is increased in any of the element trigger a ajax request which will add that number to the total sum of the element...

Comment: oh, so is it the easiest solution ? because I don't know ajax very well